# UILabel mutation on a UIButton causing text not to be displayed/ wrong alignment on display

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am trying to set a text on a `UILabel` that is a child of an `UIButton`.

The text I am changing is getting the wrong alignment. For some reason, even though the alignment is centered, it is displayed with alignment left and in other cases it does not show the changed text at all.

The only solution I could find was to run a private API called `_titleAttributesChanged`, which resolved the issue by probably calling the label to be re-rendered.

Anyone has any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

Comment: adding some code and a screenshot with your problem would be a good idea me thinks.

Comment: *"I am trying to set a text on a UILabel that is a child of an UIButton."* -- Do you mean you added a `UILabel` as a subview to a `UIButton`? Or are you trying to manipulate the internals of a standard UIButton?

Comment: Nope, the actual titleLabel on the button.
I am trying to change it's text in runtime

Comment: OK, so.. Is there a particular reason you're not using the standard `setTitle` methods (as ShivJ answered below)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no need of UILabel you can set text on button as its title using code below. Hope this will help:

in Objective-C:

```
[buttonName setTitle: @"YourText" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

in Swift:

```
buttonName.setTitle("YourText" forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Thank you! 
That worked..

I am encountering a new problem now with the fact that setting the title as per above causes a blink effect when changing.

Comment: @yanivH try to set UIButtonType to custom something like this: 
in Objective C: buttonName = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom]; 

in Swift: let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
It should work.